# pod install [!] ERROR: Parsing unable to continue due to parsing error:

Tags: ios, macos, parsing, cocoapods

When try to install pod show me this error:

```
pod install  
[!] ERROR: Parsing unable to continue due to parsing error:  
contained in the file located at   
/Users/rezakhalafi/.cocoapods/repos/master/CocoaPods-version.yml 

\---  
min: 1.0.0  
last: 1.2.0.beta.3  
prefix_lengths:  
- 1  
- 1  
- 1
```

How to fix this?

Comment: i tried "pod lib lint" but show this error: [!] Unable to find a podspec in the working directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First i removed **cocoapods**:

```
gem list --local | grep cocoapods  
gem uninstall cocoapods  
gem uninstall cocoapods-core  
gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader
```

And uninstall **Gem**:

```
gem uninstall -aIx
```

And install **Pod** just with this code again:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Go to project location and **pod install**.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the Podfile.lock file and then do a fresh pod install

Comment: This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

you can try to run in console:

```
pod spec lint
```

this command is helpful in pointing out your problem more carefully and you can figure out what goes wrong pod...

Comment: [!] No specs found in the current directory.