# CocoaPods unable to continue due to parsing error

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have created an empty Swift project in Xcode.  Then:

```
cd <project directory>
gem install cocoapods
pod init
pod install
```

Which gives the following error:

```
[!] ERROR:  Parsing unable to continue due to parsing error:  contained in the file located at /Users/<user>/.cocoapods/repos/master/CocoaPods-version.yml
```

I am aware of [a similar issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/12172) in earlier versions of CocoaPods (<1.5), but I am using version 1.6.  What might I be missing?

Comment: The `CocoaPods-version.yml` is a Yaml file. Did you check that the format its valid? I am asking becaues it says that the parser couldn't parse such file. You can check here to see if its content its valid: https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator. There are many Yaml validators and formatters online if you search for them.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the pod repo may be corrupted. Try `rm -rf ~/.cocoapods` and retry.

There are some other possible solutions at [pod install [!] ERROR: Parsing unable to continue due to parsing error:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635437/pod-install-error-parsing-unable-to-continue-due-to-parsing-error)

Comment: Interestingly, when I do this then try "pod install" I get the same error, but it points to Podfile.lock in my project directory.  So I "pod deintegrate", "rm Podfile", and "rm Podfile.lock", then "pod init" and "pod install" seem to work.  However!  When I add a pod to the Podfile (Firebase) and "pod install", I get the same error on Podfile.lock

Comment: Sharing the Podfile could help others with investigating